# ObservableCollection list does not update Listview in Xamarin project

Tags: listview, xamarin, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

I have a Xamarin project. I want to fill a list view with a List of Objects and the listview must refresh itself after any add,update or delete of the list. I have managed to do so with the add and update, but when i try to delete the Listview doesn't refresh. I use a INotifyPropertyChanged basemodel to inherit from:

```
 public class BaseModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


        protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value,
            [CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
        {
            if (object.Equals(storage, value)) return false;

            storage = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var eventHandler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (eventHandler != null)
            {
                eventHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

    }
```

The ipsettings model:

```
public class IpSettingModel : BaseModel
    {
        public IpSettingModel(String ip)
        {
            this._ip = ip;            
        }

        private string _ip = string.Empty;        
        public string ip
        {
            get { return this._ip; }
            set { this.SetProperty(ref this._ip, value); }
        }
}
```

Fill the listview with a adapter:

```
ObservableCollection<IpSettingModel> iplist = new ObservableCollection<IpSettingModel>();

    IpAdapter myadapter = new IpAdapter(this, iplist);
    ipListview.Adapter = myadapter;
```

So far so good. If i add or update a object of the list it works fine.
When i try to remove a object

```
IpManageClass.datasource.Remove(IpManageClass.datasource.Where(o => o.ip == selecteditem.ip).Single());
```

the object is removed from the ObservableCollection but the Listview does not refresh. What am i missing?

Comment: You seem to be using Xamarin Android? And what is `IpManageClass`?

Comment: Yes i am using Xamarin Android. The IpManageClass is the class that holds the static iplist that i use to fill the adapter

Comment: You might to add that class here aswell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around solution.
i added a update function on the adapter:

```
public void Update()
  {            
      NotifyDataSetChanged();
  }
```

and i call this function after the deletion of any object of my list